# Are burners and oven connected in a regular gas stove?

Tags: stove

I am using a gas stove. It is a regular gas stove, with four burners on top and an oven below. Last night, I saw a mouse running into a burner that is not working. I often put some food in the oven overnight, and was wondering if the mouse can run into the the oven below. Are the burners and the oven isolated or connected in a regular gas stove? Thanks.

Comment: If you were faster, would have free cooked meat.   Gas ovens need an exhaust port, but doubt if they use the burners.

Comment: did the mouse ever came out

Comment: @Ruskes I turned on the fire on the burner, and there was smoke coming out, and no mouse running out. I couldn't lift the metal cover covering the top of the stove except the burners, so don't know what was burned inside.  I have some food in the oven, and was wondering if the mouse can run into the the oven below. Are the burners and the oven isolated or connected in a regular gas stove?

Comment: Maybe he/she/it had a nest inside

Comment: @Ruskes "they"... if you want to be more pc

Comment: maybe it was one of those "I identify as.." too late now. You killed it ! AFIK the burners need air supply to burn.

Comment: There has to be an opening to allow combustion air into the oven, and a vent to let the hot air out. Mice can get into the _smallest_ of openings, so yes, he might be getting into your oven over night. Rather than panic about it, just set traps for this guy (and his family), then search this site for questions about finding out how they're getting into your house and sealing up their entryways.

Answer (score 1):

On gas ranges, the oven vent is usually built in to the backsplash, not the burners.

Setting a mousetrap on the adjacent countertop up against the wall or backsplash is an effective way to get rid of mice.  Put a small amount of peanut butter in the trigger where it's hard to reach.  Then turn off the lights and leave the room for 15 to 30 minutes.  This is irresistible to rodents.

After that, you'll need to seal up any holes around the foundation, thresholds, and pipes to prevent more mice from entering the home.

Comment: Thanks. Can mouse get into the oven somehow? I often boil water at night and leave the pots in the oven over night, thinking that the oven is a safe place.

Comment: @Tim I think it's possible but unlikely.  Mice can easily get to the crumbs under the oven and around burners.  If you turn on the heat or even walk by the appliance, they will run away.

Comment: Where is " under the oven"? Is it the bottom inside the oven, or outside and under the stove